# Compare a float with a defined number in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement

I have the following script, which I want to use to compare a `float` to another given float.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Enter a real number'
read n
echo n=$n

if (( $(echo "$n > 0.0" |bc -l) ))
then
    echo 'n is +ve'
elif (( $(echo "$n < 0.0" |bc -l) ))
then
    echo 'n is -ve'
else
    echo 'n is zero'
fi
```

This works fine in my OS X, however the `if` statement shows error ("not found") in Linux (Ubuntu).

What could be the more universal syntax ? (I guess one can still work with `bc` for floats).

Comment: Where exactly does the "not found" come from? Do you not have `bc` instalned, or are you using a non-Bash shell?

Comment: Your shebang indicates that `/bin/sh` is invoked to execute your script. You should try to change it to `#!/bin/bash`. The `(( ))` construct does not behave the same with all shells.

Answer (score 0):

I find it convenient to use awk:

```
if echo $n | awk '$0 > 0.0' | grep -q . ; then
    echo 'n is +ve'
elif echo $n | awk '$0 < 0.0' | grep -q . ; then
    echo 'n is -ve'
else
    echo 'n is zero'
fi
```